# airflow rendered template becomes a string

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I'm attempting to use the jinja templating to parse some json found in xcom into a dictionary. Note below that `Operator` and `templated_field` are psuedo-code.

```
def xcom_from_json(xcom):
    xcom_loaded = json.loads(xcom)
    logging.info(pformat(f'xcom loaded: {xcom_loaded}', indent=3))
    return xcom_loaded

PythonOperator(python_callable=some_callable,
           op_args=[f'{{{{ (ti.xcom_pull("{task_id}") | xcom_from_json)["data"]["stats"] }}}}'])
```

The above works, almost. In the `some_callable` method I get the parsed jinja, but it comes out as a stringified dict instead of a raw dict. This doesn't make sense, because you can see the structure being traversed as a dict in the jinja template. Does jinja stringify everything coming out of a template? If yes, is there a way to not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rendered jinja template is *always* going to return a string. What you can do instead is fetch the XCom value from within the python method instead.

```
def some_callable(task_id, **context):
    stats = json.loads(context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_id)['data']['stats'])

PythonOperator(
    ...
    python_callable=some_callable,  
    op_args=[f'{task_id}'],
    provide_context=True)
```

Note that you must provide context, which gives the python method the same access to values a jinja template has.